# css background image adapt dimension

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to figure out how to resize a background image only if it is bigger than the div which contains it using only CSS.

```
<div id="container>
</div>

#container{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url("...myimagepath");
}
```

If the image is bigger than 100x100 px it should be resized but if it is smaller I need to keep it center and not adapted. In my code it works as aspected for images smaller than the div while the image is not resized for bigger ones.

Comment: Found this an interesting question cos repeating backgrounds can look a bit naff sometimes as can backgrounds that fall out of the container.

Answer (score -1):

You can frig it by putting the image in a div that sits in the background.

So HTML:

```
<div id="container>
  <div id="background">
    <img src="...myimagepath">
  </div>
  Container content here.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 100px;        /* Your original dimensions */
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;  /* Lets anything in it be positioned relative to it */
}

#background{
    width: 100%;         /* Same width as parent container */
    height: 100%;        /* Ditto height */
    position: absolute;  /* Take out of document flow. Default position 0,0 */
    z-index: -1;         /* Push it behind anything else in its container */
}

#background img {
    max-width: 100%;     /* Don't let it get wider than its container */
    max-height: 100%;    /* Nor taller */
    display: block;      /* Lets margins be set (otherwise in-line) */
    position: absolute:  /* Lets us position it */
    top: 0;              /* Put it at the top ... */
    left: 0;             /* on the far left ... */
    bottom: 0;           /* and at the bottom (makes sense later) */
    right: 0;            /* and the far right (ditto) */
    margin: auto;        /* Best compromise between left/right & top/bottom = centre */
}
```

I seem to half remember there might be the odd browser that doesn't treat the zeros for top, left, etc properly. If that's true, use a value like 1px instead.

Comment: My specs require to use the background image and not <img>, is there a way to do it avoiding <img> ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of one. Perhaps ask the reason for it being spec'd that way? If it's so the image doesn't print, you can deal with that in css. It may be you can give them exactly what they want and make them happy, just not in the way they thought it ought to be done.

Comment: It's a performance reason, it is not web but embedded system ;)

Comment: Ah, then sorry I can't help. Maybe have several identical images but different sizes and use media queries to target the appropriate one? (But I know nothing about embedded systems so that might not even make sense as far as I know.)

Comment: My solution is to append an <img> hidden with real size. Get the dimensions of the <img>. Set the background image and resize it if it is bigger than the div.